# Novel, title SPD, Selective Pigmentation Disease

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find a book for my dad, he claims it has been 'cancelled' by the internet and that's why he can't Google it (sigh).

So he thinks it was a sci fi novel called SPD, Selective Pigmentation Disease by C P Snow? Doesn't bode well, does it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._P._Snow#Fiction / http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?25210- I'm not seeing it at any of the usual places

Comment: Real stretch - it's not the Dean Koontz Moonlight Bay series? Protagonist is Chris Snow, who has Xeroderma pigmentosum...

Comment: @Michael that's exactly where I went as well. The author has only written 2 of the 3 from the series, but it's in no way 'cancelled' by the internet.

Comment: Easy to find if you look for the correct series - I guess if you misremember details you'd struggle to find anything?

Comment: Looks like "Selective Pigmentation Disorder" was perfectly right after all!  Oddly enough, Goodreads's author biography for Haggard actually compares him to C. P. Snow, so perhaps their styles are so similar that that's how the mistake arose.  Goes to show, just because somebody has a conspiracy theory about something doesn't mean that it doesn't exist, or that there is a conspiracy.

Answer (score 21):

Could he be referring to William Haggard's *[The Doubtful Disciple](http://www.trashfiction.co.uk/doubtful_disciple.html)*?

> 'Germs aren't nationality-conscious, germs don't ask to see people's passports,' Laver said.
> 'They haven't so far,' Dominy said.
> But now ... now that the scientists had discovered **SPD - Selective Pigmentation Disease** - they could see the unthinkable consequences if such a hellbrew were poured out into the world.

[image: Cover of the "The doubtful disciple". The tagline on the cover is "Cool, clever, crime for the connoisseur". The cover shows a yellow sign on a barbed wire fence, in front of a snowy asphalt road. The sign reads: "Official Secrets Act | Prohibited Place | Photography Not Authorised". There is a second sign underneath that reads "Permission to proceed on this road may be assumed when the gate is open but public must keep to the road".]